# How does Angular makes native element connect with its value accessor API?

Tags: angular, dom, dom-events

I'm creating web components for a project. I'd love to make those web components behave in forms like native elements in Angular : that automatically, `[(ngModel)]` and / or `[FormControl]` works on them.

I thought that was impossible because of the type of the events fired by my web-component. Those are DOM Events that only accept a custom value in the `detail` field, and Angular only checks the `value` field. So I wrapped up my web-components into an Angular component which implemented the `ngValueAccessor` API.

But now that I think of it, native element like `input` does communicate well with Angular API even though they are native and, I assume, use the same event type as my web-component.

How so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular uses default class implementations for the native elements: https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor#class-implementations

An `input` uses the [DefaultValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/DefaultValueAccessor). It also has a `ngDefaultControl` selector.

> This value accessor is used by default for `<input type="text">` and `<textarea>` elements, but you could also use it for custom components that have similar behavior and do not require special processing. In order to attach the default value accessor to a custom element, add the ngDefaultControl attribute as shown below.
>
> > `<custom-input-component ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="value"></custom-input-component>`